# Can I see the view hierarchy I have in my app while debugging in Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiview

I am debugging my iOS app and since I have a view push/dismiss calls, I want to make sure I don't have any views in my stack that I wouldn't expect.  Is it possible to see this in the Xcode debugger?

Comment: ViewControllers which pushed/popped are managed by UINavigationController. You can print log of UINavigationController's viewControllers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might find lldb comes to the rescue with 'recursiveDescription'. Simply set a breakpoint at the point where you are interested in the view hierarchy. If for example you want everything in the window you can type

```
(lldb) po [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] firstObject] recursiveDescription]
```

Alternatively, I often find that when debugging views I am mostly interested in the hierarchy for a particular view. In that instance you can hook straight in to the point in code you are curious about (for example the viewDidAppear: method) and type:

```
(lldb) po [self.view recursiveDescription]
```

**Note:** With Xcode 6 Apple have added realtime view debugging which you can access from the debug bar. [image: Real Time View Debugging Xcode 6]

Comment: Thanks, this button looks helpful.  I will look into updating to Xcode 6

Answer (score 0):

As all of your view controllers should be managed by the navigation controller, you should be able to do something like this:

```
NSArray * controllerArray = [[self navigationController] viewControllers];

for (UIViewController *controller in controllerArray){
   //Code here.. e.g. print their titles to see the array setup;
   NSLog(@"%@",controller.title);
}
```

Taken from here: [How to iterate all the UIViewControllers on the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7813607/how-to-iterate-all-the-uiviewcontrollers-on-the-app)

Answer (score 0):

There is also [Reveal.app](https://revealapp.com/) which provide much more features than Xcode realtime view debugging, has a nicer UI and integrates with [AppCode](https://www.jetbrains.com/objc/).