# FBLoginView not showing up when using storyboard in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, facebook

I am building a test application using the Facebook API, and I'm trying to simply add a FBLoginView to a view when learning about Single Sign On.  I've followed the Facebook documentation thoroughly, and for some reason, despite carefully following the steps, as well as looking at the sample code that is provided, cannot figure out why the FBLoginView is not showing up when I run the app.

1. I have added the Facebook framework to my project
2. Ironically, the Profile Picture View appears (FBProfilePictureView)
3. I have modified the custom class so that it is FBLoginView

This is the relevant code that I have in the AppDelegate.m file:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [FBLoginView class];
    [FBProfilePictureView class];

    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {

    return [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication];
}
```

and this is the code that I have in the ViewController.m file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [self toggleHiddenState:NO];
    self.loginStatus.text = @"";
    self.loginButton.readPermissions = @[@"public_profile", @"email"];
}

- (void)toggleHiddenState:(BOOL)shouldHide {

    self.userName.hidden = shouldHide;
    self.email.hidden = shouldHide;
    self.profilePictureView.hidden = shouldHide;
    self.loginStatus.hidden = shouldHide;
    self.loginButton.hidden = shouldHide;
}
```

Here is also a screenshot of my storyboard in interface builder:

[image]

Can anyone see what it is I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You know with Xcode 6 you can debug your view hierarchy to find the missing view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
FBLoginView *loginview = [[FBLoginView alloc] init];
loginview.frame = CGRectOffset(loginview.frame, 5, 5);
#ifdef __IPHONE_7_0
#ifdef __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_7_0
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setEdgesForExtendedLayout:)]) {
        loginview.frame = CGRectOffset(loginview.frame, 5, 25);
    }
#endif
#endif
#endif
    loginview.delegate = self;

    [self.view addSubview:loginview];

    [loginview sizeToFit];
```

Add this code in your viewDidLoad

Hope this resolves your problem...

Comment: Hi Sarath, thanks very much for your reply.  Can you explain why your code works?  In your solution, I am programmatically adding the FBLoginView to the main view and it is appearing as it should.  Why is it that the view that I added is not appearing when I do it in IB?  Another issue I discovered is when I comment out the the block of code inside the: #if/#endif statements, BOTH FBLoginView's appear (yours, as well as the one I added in IB).  Any idea why?  Thanks once again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

With Xcode 6 you can debug your view hierarchy and see exactly whats going on (iOS 8 and up). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24728326/can-i-see-the-view-hierarchy-i-have-in-my-app-while-debugging-in-xcode/24732640#24732640) is a post on SO that deals with how this can be done.

That being said your constraints are probably configured wrong for the loginView. Try adding an explicit width and height constraint before debugging. If that fails drill down into the hierarchy to find the FBLoginView.